# JAVA: What values does getRGB() return from a transparent pixel?

Tags: java, colors, rgb, bufferedimage

If i were to `int RGB = image.getRGB(x,y)`, where x and y were the coordinates of a transparent pixel of `image`, what would the value of RGB be? Null?

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978228/java-bufferedimage-how-to-know-if-a-pixel-is-transparent).

Comment: Transparent means that the *alpha component* is `0`. So the RGB value may be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be basically anything. The alpha component does not correlate with the **RGB** component.

So for example if you have an **ARGB** object with (0, 45, 34, 23) and one with (0, 56, 78, 89) then they are both transparent so you don't have to care about color.

**But** if they are (10, 45, 34, 23), (10, 56, 78, 89) then the difference is visible. Alpha(**A**) tells how opaque/transparent is something. The rest (**RGB**) tells the color of it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're working on an image with an Alpha RGB [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) you should use [getAlpha()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getAlpha%28%29).