# Comparing 2 images with transparency area in Java

Tags: java, image

For an automation tool I'm working on I need to compare 2 images.
My code works perfectly when I have "normal" images, but it fails when one of the images has a transparent area.

I'm reducing the color between the images for each pixel and creating a negative image that shows the difference. For images with transparent area the negative image is whole white, I can't see any shape or other info.

How to ignore the transparent area (shown in the images as gray color)?

[image: First image]
[image: Second image]

My code:

```
  private static BufferedImage createDiffImage(BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2) {
    BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(img1.getWidth(), img1.getHeight(), img1.getType());
    int color;
    for(int x = 0; x < img1.getWidth(); x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < img1.getHeight(); y++) {
            color = Math.abs(img2.getRGB(x, y) - img1.getRGB(x, y));
            result.setRGB(x, y, color);
        }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Maybe this one helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978228/java-bufferedimage-how-to-know-if-a-pixel-is-transparent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
  private static BufferedImage createDiffImage(BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2) {
    BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(img1.getWidth(), img1.getHeight(), img1.getType());
    for(int x = 0; x < img1.getWidth(); x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < img1.getHeight(); y++) {
            Color c1 = new Color(img1.getRGB(x,y));
            Color c2 = new Color(img2.getRGB(x,y));
            int alpha = 255;
            int red = Math.abs(c1.getRed() - c2.getRed());
            int green = Math.abs(c1.getGreen() - c2.getGreen());
            int blue = Math.abs(c1.getBlue() - c2.getBlue());
            Color negativeColor = new Color(red,green,blue, alpha);
            result.setRGB(x, y, negativeColor.getRGB());
        }
    return result;
}
```